# Binding ttk Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a bind_class to a ttk Entry widget but it does not work. It only work properly when I bind each Entry widget separately.
Would you help me?

Thank you in advance

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import*
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def clicker(event):
    myLabel = ttk.Label( root, text = 'You clicked a button' )
    myLabel.pack()

myEntry = ttk.Entry( root )
myEntry.pack()

root.bind_class( 'Entry', '<Button-1>', clicker )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make it `'TEntry'` instead of `'Entry'`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I suggest writing an answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily. You are allowed to [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but be sure to read [answer] first.

Answer (score 2):

When I replaced 'Entry' by 'TEntry' it worked perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).